# DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined

Tags: python, django, python-idle

when i input `from django.db import models` into IDLE,the result throw a exception named `Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.`
why does this exception occur and how i can fix it

Answer (score 8):

You can use **python manage.py shell** instead of using **IDLE**.

**manage.py** reads and uses django settings including `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`.

Answer (score 6):

Ensure,  if not, follow the way to Quick Start:

Assumptions:

1. You have installed python on `c:\` i.e., `c:\python27`
2. You have installed Django 1.3 in same folder i.e., `c:\python27`

Step 1:

First you need to set system path for django-admin.py with:

```
 set DJANGO_PATH="c:\python27\scripts"
```

so that you will able to run django-admin.py from anywhere where you want to create DJango project.

Step 2:

Now go to c:\python27\ and run following syntax to create test project:

```
   django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

Here "mysite" is our project name, you can choose whatever you want.

Now you project is created you can check this in c:\python27\ in folder named mysite\

Step 3:

Now go to python shell at c:\python27

set environment variable "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" with:

```
   >>> import os
   >>> os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='mysite.settings'
```

Here " mysite " is project name which we created in step 2.

All basic setups are done now you can run your command

```
 from django.db import models<br>
```

If problem still persist please review all steps or reply me.

Answer (score 5):

Don't run `django-admin.py` for anything other than the initial project creation. For everything after that, use `manage.py`, which takes care of the finding the settings.

Answer (score 3):

It occurred because you forgot to [supply the Django project settings](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/). You can fix it by supplying them.

Comment: and how i can supply it in windows

Comment: Exactly the same way. Unless you're using the first method in cmd.exe, in which case you'd use `set`.

Comment: my question is how i can fix it,eg,may i add one line code in one py file