# Django: manage.py ImportError because environment variable is undefined

Tags: python, django

I've just cloned a Django project using Mercurial to a Windows machine that I have set up Python 2.7 on. When I try to run `manage.py` (with or without a command), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jes.000\Documents\project\manage.py", line 30, in <module>
    import django.core.servers.basehttp
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 26, in <module>
    from django.views import static
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\static.py", line 95, in <module>
    template_translatable = ugettext_noop(u"Index of %(directory)s")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", line 75, in gettext_noop
    return _trans.gettext_noop(message)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__

    if settings.USE_I18N:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 184, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." %ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

I understand that manage.py is supposed to set that environment variable. I also understand that I might be getting this error because the project is not in the python path... but adding it manually seems like it shouldn't be necessary. Isn't manage.py supposed to resolve this issue as well?

Edit: I've just tested and found that it does the exact same thing under Linux.

Edit: Here's a useful discovery: *I only get this error if I install Django via PIP*, it works fine if I install the python-django package on Ubuntu. So there's something that the debian package is doing that PIP isn't. Maybe the debian package sets some environment variables? I need to figure that out, since I'm trying to develop on Windows.

Edit: I think I've found the problem, but not a solution. Working on an Ubuntu machine, when I install Django via PIP (`pip install django`), this project doesn't work with the error I gave. If I create a new project (`django-admin startproject testproject`) and try that it works, and it consists of `manage.py` in the created folder, with another folder that contains everything else. Like this:

```
+-testproject
  +-manage.py
  +-testproject
    +-__init__.py
    +-etc.
```

When I install the Debian package (`apt-get install python-django`) the project I'm trying to work on works, and if I create a test project (`django-admin startproject testproject`) it has a folder structure like this:

```
+-testproject
  +-manage.py
  +-__init__.py
  +-etc.
```

Notice the difference: the PIP Django package seems to put the manage.py outside of the python module that is the app, while the Debian package puts manage.py inside the module. I assume that this is due to the two packages being of a different version of Django, in between which they changed the structure, because the two packages doing this differently doesn't make any sense.

So my problem is that the project I'm trying to develop was originally generated using the version that's been Debian packaged, while on my Windows machine I'm trying to use the version of Django from pip.

The trouble is that I'm not certain how to fix the problem. Naively moving the manage.py up a directory so it's above the project folder doesn't work, because this 'debian-package version' manage.py tries to just `import settings`, which fails if it's not in the same folder as settings.py. But somewhere else in Django, something seems to be expecting the project itself to be at //settings.py (as would be the case if the pip version of django-admin was used) rather than at /settings.py (as is the case if the debian-package version is used).

If I look it up, the version in the Ubuntu repositories is 1.3.1, while the version in PyPI is 1.4. Look at the release notes for 1.4, and hey:

> An updated default project layout and manage.py that removes the
>   “magic” from prior versions. And for those who don’t like the new
>   layout, you can use custom project and app templates instead!

But... shouldn't projects generated with the 1.3 layout still work under 1.4..?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479493/django-settings-module-is-undefined

Comment: My understanding is that the purpose of manage.py (which is really just a wrapper to django-admin) is to eliminate the need to set those values globally or supply them manually, though.

Comment: Are you running `manage.py` from within the project directory or outside?

Comment: within. The CWD is the directory that contains manage.py, settings.py, etc.

Comment: django 1.4 did change the default project layout, but I can confirm that it makes no different and you can run the previous structure under django 1.4. Basically, set your pythonpath, use my recommended method in my answer (which does work), or set the environment var to point to the settings file

Comment: So are you saying that it is not possible to make this project work under 1.4 without setting an environment variable manually? that's just frustrating to me since I don't need to do this under 1.3.

Comment: I'm actually not sure why you are having pathing problems to be honest. I just tested starting a 1.3 and 1.4 project from any directory, with default manage.py files, and they start right up.

Comment: Someone in Django's IRC has responded to me. I'll post an answer if I figure this out. I assume something is weird about this project in particular, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Please post the directory structure of the stuff you downloaded. If you missed an __init__.py something like this can happen.

Comment: Projects generated with the 1.3 layout will still run under Django 1.4 as long as you continue to use the same manage.py you used in 1.3. Something else is going on here.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this has changed in more recent version of django, but the default `manage.py` simply tries to import the `settings.py` file and start the manager. You would be expected to put the project in your PYTHONPATH, or to put the settings.py into your DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE variable, by default.

You can modify the `manage.py` to be a bit smarter with this snippet:

**manage.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from django.core.management import execute_manager

...

import settings

import os
project = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(__file__))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = '%s.settings' % project

if __name__ == "__main__":
    execute_manager(settings)
```

Now you can run manage.py from any location, since it will always explicitly set up the path to the settings.py file.

Comment: When I try modifying it like this I get an error that importing failed (no module named project.settings), asking whether or not it's in sys.path. I don't think I should have to add the project directory to the python path anywhere... shouldn't that work automatically? See my update about the debian package, I assume that's significant.

Comment: @jcrawfordor: Was the name of the top level directory "project"?

Comment: not actually project, but the same as the name of the project (I'm not using the real name).

Answer (score 1):

You may add the following code to the file **manage.py** ,like this:

```
from django.conf import settings  
settings.configure()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed due to the difference in default layouts between 1.3 and 1.4. Normally Django 1.3 projects will work under 1.4, so something else is going on here that I can't quite figure out. I have established that the problem isn't platform-dependent.

I couldn't figure out the exact problem but I did figure out a fix. That was:

1. Create a new project under Django 1.4 and poach its manage.py file. After changing the project name, this file works as a manage.py. I named it 'manage14.py' so that the original manage.py would be left for my colleagues using Django 1.3.
2. Add the directory above the one that the project was in to the global PYTHONPATH. This is not an ideal solution, but it allowed an unmodified Django 1.4 manage.py to load the project without having to convert the project to Django 1.4's organization.

As soon a practical, I plan to convert the project to the Django 1.4 format since it seems to be better anyway, particularly from the perspective of avoiding this kind of problem. Unfortunately I'll have to wait until the Ubuntu repo's get 1.4 so that my colleagues will be up to the same version I am on Windows using PyPI.