# ImportError: cannot import name MPTTModel

Tags: django, django-admin, django-mptt

I did the steps at the tutorial " http://django-mptt.github.com/django-mptt/tutorial.html "

but it still give me the import error , I double check the code for the mptt and found the class MPTTMODEL exist in the mptt>model file

```
Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x1ec4710>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 91, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/validation.py", line 30, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/loading.py", line 158, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/loading.py", line 67, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/loading.py", line 88, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/kareemhashem/espace/sharek/core/models.py", line 12, in <module>
    from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey
ImportError: cannot import name MPTTModel
```

Comment: Please, update your answer and show your Traceback

Comment: If you've come to this post recently, you're probably following an old tutorial as I did. Since django CMS 3.1 MPTT has been replaced by MP: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/upgrade/3.1.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One thing you could try: Go to the console and type: `python` (to get the python console) and then enter: `from mptt.models import MPTTModel`

If this gives you an error than mptt is not correctly installed.

If you are using [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/) you could easily do: `pip install django-mptt` or you might try `pip install django-mptt --upgrade` to update your installation. It might be that your installation did not succeeded.

If you are not using pip or virtualenv I highly recommend it. The start is a bit tough, but it is worse to install it. See these resources to get started: [1](http://jontourage.com/2011/02/09/virtualenv-pip-basics/), [2](http://rubayeet.com/2011/03/04/getting-started-with-pipvirtualenv/)

If you have successfully installed mptt and you still cannot import it, the folder where you placed mptt into is probably not accessible to python. Therefore add the path where mptt lives to your PYTHONPATH. See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath) how to do it.

Comment: Thank you, I did try to import it from python console and get the error:

" ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined. "

Comment: ok, than type "python manage.py shell" and try to import again.

Comment: regarding the python shell and missing DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479493/django-settings-module-is-undefined

Comment: Thank you, it seems it wasn't installed correctly , but when I installed it usin < pip install > it imported well