# Django import error saying django settings environment variable is undefined

Tags: django, django-admin

I have created a project sample and an app sampapp on windows xp While I'm trying to use the command `sqlall`, I'm getting the following error.

> C:\Python27\Django-1.3.1\django\bin>django-admin.py sqlall sampapp

```
 Traceback (most recent call last): File
 "C:\Python27\Django-1.3.1\django\bin\django-admin.py", line 5, in
 <module > management.execute_from_command_line() File
 "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",
 line 429, in execute_from_command_line utility.execute() File
 "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",
 line 379, in execute
 self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv) File
 "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",
 line 261, in fetch_command klass = load_command_class(app_name,
 subcommand) File
 "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",
 line 67, in load_command_class module =
 import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name)) File
 "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in
 im port_module __import__(name) File
 "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\sqlall.py"
 , line 4, in <module> from django.core.management.sql import sql_all
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\sql.py",
 line 6, in <module> from django.db import models File
 "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 14, in
 <modul e> if not settings.DATABASES: File
 "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 276,
 in __getattr__ self._setup() File
 "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 40, in
 _set up raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
 ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable
 DJANGO_SE TTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

Can someone help me to solve this.?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479493/django-settings-module-is-undefined..Take a look here

Comment: Thanks for the link Raunak. But if I'm trying to use shell as explained the above link, I'm getting the same error. I'm not getting where am i going wrong. Plz see the following error. ------------------C:\Python27\Django-1.3.1\django\bin>django-admin.py shell
Error: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS
_MODULE is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to your project directory and run the local manage.py there.

```
C:\...\my_project_where_sampapp_lives\> python manage.py sqlall sampapp
```

You're using 'django-admin.py' when you should be using 'python manage.py'

```
$ django-admin.py shell
Error: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
$ python manage.py shell
...
>>> print "now it works"
```

Comment: I didnot understand clearly.. can u explain me more clearly.  Thank u

Comment: You created a project somewhere, right?  Navigate your command prompt to where you created the project.  Then, run 'python manage.py sqlall sampapp' from that directory.

Comment: No I'm pretty sure that I've created project in the exact path.

Comment: You created a project with the name "bin" inside of C:\Python27\Django-1.3.1\django\?  If so, try running 'python manage.py sqlall sampapp' there

Answer (score 0):

DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE should be specified,
I usually add this line to my .bashrc file:

export PYTHONPATH=. DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=*yoursettingsfile*

Answer (score 0):

Django-admin.py is looking for your projects `settings.py` file which it is not able to locate  thus it Raises the ImportError. Seems like you did not navigate to your project directory while using django-admin.py command.

All you need to do is to navigate to your project directory. Something like:

(assuming your project name is my project)

```
cd myproject
```

and then run

```
django-admin.py sqlall sampapp
```

Comment: But django-admin.py is in bin folder not in project folder. How can it recognize the command.

Comment: django-admin.py should be recognized if python is added to your `Environment Variable -> PATH`. just try running it from the project directory.